# C++ dynamic and static libraries linking with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, antlr, ld

I need some help with C++ compilation, as I'm obviously missing something.

I've created .so library (let's call it mylib) depending on other .so library I wrote (mylib2) and some simple program using it. Also the second library depends on [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). I use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) for building both libs and they are compiling and installing just fine. But when I try to compile the program:

```
cmd> g++ program.cpp -lmylib
```

I get

```
/usr/local/lib/libmylib2.so.0: undefined reference to `antlr::CharScanner::traceOut(char const*)'
```

ANTLR appears to be static lib, so I tried

```
cmd> g++ program.cpp -lmylib -Wl,-Bstatic -lantlr
```

But then all I get is

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
```

I've got two questions here:

1) Why can't mylib2 see antlr? I should mention, that I use my own cmake find script, can this be a problem?

```
find_package(ANTLR REQUIRED)
include_directories(${ANTLR_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

2) What does the second error mean? Why can't ld find libgcc_s?

I will really appreciate any help.

**EDIT**

I should mention I am using ANTLR 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man ld` (GNU ld): `-Bstatic` - Do not link against shared libraries. You may use this option multiple times on the command line: it affects library searching for -l options which follow it. So you should manually enable using dynamic libraries after `-lantlr`. Please remember, that linking a static library not being compiled with `-fPIC` option may result in non-relocatable code and longer application startup time http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/41

Comment: Thanks for quick reply :) But when I type 
    g++ test.cpp -lmylib -Wl,-Bstatic -lantlr -Wl,-Bdynamic
I still get 'undefined reference' errors.
Also, is there a way of including antlr in mylib2 so I wouldn't need to specify it with every program using mylib?

Comment: Well, roughly speaking a shared library in Linux (ELF) almost doesn't differ from other ELF binaries, so, yes, you can compile it like this: `gcc -shared -o libmylib2.so mylib2_obj1.o mylib2_obj2.o /path/to/libantlr.a`... But actually I would link against a dynamic version of libantlr if it exists in the system.